# Update: Display First Occurance in ForEach loop in EJS and Node JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I want to display all the data from Timetable Collections but i want the data only display Classroom name only One. For Example i have 2 Fields of `classroom_name` which is `6 Usaha`. I Want only 1 of `6 Usaha` in the table in EJS.

Right know, system have display the data according to number of records in Collections which in this case is 2.

**Actual Result**

```
6 Usaha
6 Usaha
```

**Expected Result**

```
6 Usaha
```

This is my code for the implementation.

**EJS File**

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Class</th>
                                                <th>Settings</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <% timetable.forEach(function (timetable) { %>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><%= timetable.classroom.classroom_name %></td>
                                                <td><a class="button" href="/timetable_class/view/<%= timetable.classroom._id %>"</a>View&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <% }) %>
                                        </tbody>

                                    </table>
```

**Server File**

```
router.get('/timetable_class',mid, function(req,res){
  Teacher.findById(req.session.userId).exec(function (error, user){
    if (error){
      return next(error);
    }else
    {
      Timetable.find({year:currentYear}).populate('classroom').exec(function(err, timetable) 
      {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(currentYear);
        console.log(timetable);
        res.render('admin_content/view_timetable_table',{timetable:timetable,  user:user});
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What should happen to the other document(s) with duplicate `classroom.classroom_name` value? Do you just want to display the first occurrence alone?

Comment: Yup. I just want to display the first occurrence. @Tunmee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter out timetable documents with duplicate `classroom.classroom_name` value such that only one such document exists (the first one) for rendering. It's a little bit tricky because `classrrom_name` property is only available after a lookup on another collection(classroom).

While the obvious solution of using the regular javascript filtering on your existing query result would work, a better and more efficient way to do the filtering would be to do it at the database level. This would help avoid fetching a lot of documents you do not need.

You can make use of MongoDB aggregation to find, lookup(similar to populate) and group the timetable document based on their `classroom.classroom_name` value, consequently the result of the db query would be such that `classroom.classroom_name` value is unique for each timetable document. Code is below:

```
router.get('/timetable_class',mid, function(req,res){
  Teacher.findById(req.session.userId).exec(function (error, user){
    if (error){
      return next(error);
    } else
    {
      // In place of .find() and .populate(), I'm using .aggregate()
      Timetable.aggregate([
        {
          // This is doing the same thing as the previous .find()
          $match: { year: currentYear }
        },
        // The stages($lookup and $set) below are doing what the previous
       // .populate() was doing
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "Classroom",
            localField: "classroom",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "classroom"
          }
        },
        {
          $set: { classroom: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$classroom", 0] } }
        },
        // Group the documents with their classroom.classroom_name value
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$classroom.classroom_name",
            doc: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
          }
        },
        // A bit of cleanup 
        { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$doc" } }
      ]).exec(function(err, timetable) 
      {
        // The query output is such that `classroom.classroom_name`
        // value is unique for each document
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(currentYear);
        console.log(timetable);
        res.render('admin_content/view_timetable_table',{timetable:timetable,  user:user});
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Helpful links:

- [MongoDB Database Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/).
- [MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline Stages](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/)

Comment: Thanks for the solution!